# Pixel perfect pen size in GIMP

Tags: gimp, pen-tool

When I use the pen and I put 1.0 size, it draws a 1x1 pixel square. But after that, it goes like this:

- At 2.0 size, 3x3 square.
- At 3.0 size, 3x3 square.
- At 4.0 size, 3x3 square.
- At 5.0 size, 5x5 square.
- At 6.0 size, 5x5 square.

How do I make it that a set pen size draws a square of this exact size in pixels?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a one pixel pencil brush in Gimp?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/29932/how-to-create-a-one-pixel-pencil-brush-in-gimp) Not exact but the answers have some merit.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution thanks to Ovaryraptor's comment.

The problem is that the "Pixel" brush of the pen is not a pixel. It's a 3x3 square.

To fix the problem, I created my own Pixel brush which is an actual pixel (1x1 square). From there, changing the size value of the pen gives the right square size.

Comment: There's actually another pixel brush in the brush list already, which is a 1x1 pixel square.

Comment: @MichaelSchumacher Thank you. The 1x1 pixel brush was hidden way down in my brush list inbetween my dozens of custom brushes. It should be at the beginning of the list really.